# Verifone Application Download over TCP/IP

Tags: embedded, kiosk, point-of-sale, verifone

I have verifone Nurit POS. I want to perform a remote app download. But I don't know how to make my Server ready for it. Can anyone help me with this.
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Well, you should install an ftp server on ur server. I can suggest you Filezilla Server( Thats what I am using). After that, you should make filezilla server's configuration to point at a file, you ll keep your remote download app.

Then, trigger the remote download with ftp servers username and password. Done! This is how I do it with Nurit 8010. I hope this was what you meant.